# UUID faltante en /etc/fstab

Tags: boot, uuid

luego de un mal reinicio de mi pc, fui dirigido al modo de emergencia (solo uso de CLI). Poseo 2 discos duros y no puedo acceder a la partición /dev/sdb3, con lo que, siguiendo el siguiente hilo, se sugiere localizar la particion corrupta y repararla con `ntfsfix`, en mi caso `ntfsfix /dev/sdb1` https://wiki.salud.gob.sv/wiki/Reparar_error_de_montaje_en_sistema_de_archivos_NTFS_($MFTMirr_does_not_match_$MFT)

al correr dicho comando obtengo esto:

> Mounting volume... NTFS signature is missing
> FAILED
>
> Attempting to correct errors... NTFS signature is missing FAILED
>
> Failed to startup volume: Invalid argument
>
> Trying the alternative boot sector
>
> Unrecoverable error
>
> Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk

Al revisar el directorio /dev/sdb1, me di ceunta que este ya no existia,asi que segui lo propuesto por: https://www.enmimaquinafunciona.com/pregunta/135568/permitir-el-funcionamiento-en-modo-de-emergencia

Acá se sugiere revisar /etc/fstab con `cat` y me di cuenta que el UUID correspondiente a /dev/sdb1 no se encontraba; con esto, ¿debo agregar a /etc/fstab una linea indicando el UUID de /dev/sdb1? , aparte de agregar el UUID, que otros caracteres debo agregar a dicha linea si es que es necesario?

dejo acá el resultado de `sudo blkid` (indicando los UUIDs de las particiones)

[image: resultado sudo blkid]

Y acá el resultado de `cat /etc/fstab`

[image: resultado de cat /etc/fstab]

Gracias por detenerse a leer :)

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Comment: tu problema esta relacionada al manejo de aplicaciones en el sistema operativo, y no a algo relacionado a los objetivos del sitio (Desarrollo y programación).